AWS amplify federated SSO with redirect
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify/utils';
Hub.listen('auth', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
}); 

How this suppose to trigger if redirect occurs with federated logins like Google
signInWithRedirect({provider: "Google"});

is there way to use different _target in this workflow ?
